# React Preact Signals array not rerendering when it changes value

Tags: reactjs, preact-signal

I have an array signals that are being rendered in UI using map, but everytime I put a new value in it, it doesnt rerender and show in UI the new value.

```
import React from "react";
import { signal, effect } from "@preact/signals-react";
let varA = 0
const count = signal([0]);
const App = () => {
  effect(() => console.log(count.value));
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {count.value.map((count) => { return <li key={varA++}>{count}</li> })}
      </ul>

      <button onClick={() => count.value = [...count.value, 1]}>{count}</button>
    </div>
  )
};

export default App
```

Id like to know how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't followed the usage instructions. Please read the [Integration Instructions](https://github.com/preactjs/signals/tree/main/packages/react#react-integration) and use the Babel plugin or `useSignals()`.

Comment: I see! Im sorry, I didnt see this part of docs, mb! Thank you so much for giving me this information, it worked!